# How to handle a single publisher clogging up my RabbitMQ's queue

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

In my last project, I am using MassTransit (2.10.1) with RabbitMQ.
On some scenarios, a producer is allowed to send a bulk of messages to the queue.

For example - the user set to a bulk notification to his list of contacts - the list could be as large as 100000 contacts on some cases. This will send a message per each contact to the queue (I need to keep track of each message). Now since - as I understand - messages are being processed in the order of entrance, that user is clogging up the queue for a large amount of time while another user, which may have done a simple thing such as send a test message to himself, waits for the processing to end.

I have considered separating queues for regular VS bulk operations but this still doesn't solve the problem for small bulks (user with dozens of contacts waiting for users with hundred thousands) and causes extra maintenance.

The ideal solution for me - I think - would involve manipulating the routing in such a way that the consumer will be handling x messages from the same user, move the X messages from the next user, than again, and than moving back to the beginning of the queue, until all messages are processed.

Is that possible? Is there a better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will to have to write code to manage this yourself. RabbitMQ doesn't really have any built-in mechanism to handle a scenario like this, without your code getting involved.

If you want to process a few at a time from bulk, then back to normal, then back to bulk, you'll need 2 queues and code to manage which one is being pulled from, when.

Comment: Thanks. does it make any sense to spawn a queue per user in this scenario?

Comment: To this point, a saga could easily handle the logic to decide whether you use a consumer to handle small requests, or a bulk consumer. 2 consumers would mean 2 separate queues.

Answer (score 0):

Just my opinion, seeing as how there is no built in way to my knowledge...Have you considered using whatever storage you are using to store the notifications, then just publish one message, with a List of Notifications, store it in you DB, and then have a retrieve notifications for user consumer. the response would be one message, it may have a massive payload, but even if that gets bogged down, add a skip and take property to the message and force it to be between 0 and 50 (or whatever). In what scenario would you want to show a user 100,000 notifications at once?

Comment: i have considered that, but i do not like this option since it bypass my queuing mechanism only to put in another queue.